# Moving SharePoint to the Cloud

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, site

I work in IT and Im in control of our corporate site on a design level. I do not do any of the back end work such as server set up as we are part of a larger organisation that looks after all our infrastructure for us and give me full control rights on our own SharePoint site. 
My boss has tasked me in looking to move our site to the cloud as we are all working off Office 365 and would like to exploit the use of having everything in one place.

Does anyone our there have any advice on this move and can you give me any idea where I should start?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you have?

Comment: If there is tax,financial data or client personal data ,  then you should consider no to go for cloud .

Comment: SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to consider when migrating to SP online. Things most important to ask are what functionality to you currently have and can the cloud support it. Not everything in an on-premises installation can be done online.

You need to do a complete analysis as suggested here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852518.aspx

http://redmondmag.com/Articles/2013/04/01/Key-Piece.aspx

There is no support for content migration, so everything has to be done manually or through a third party migration tool.

There is no support for server code only apps using the new App model. So if you have any custom c# / server side code, you have to migrate that manually.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114(v=office.15).aspx

The better question to ask your boss would be why does he think it is beneficial to move to the cloud? Is it to save on infrastructure costs? Is he ok with having Microsoft handle all your data? Hybrid solutions are perfectly acceptable and depending on the complexity of your setup, may be a wiser choice:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn607308(v=office.15).aspx