# Migration Share Point 2010 to office 365 cloud without 3rd party tools

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-365

Is there any way to Migration Share Point 2010 to office 365 cloud with out using 3rd Party tool.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for an answer to this - if your SharePoint Farm is relatively simple i.e. only used for Document management and no custom solutions you can do a 2-step migration process, first migrate to SharePoint 2013 and then migrate to SharePoint Online.

You can also used Microsoft's SharePoint migrator tool (SPMT) which is free of cost details of which can be found here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Answer (score 0):

If you mean content, then there is no way to migrate except through a 3rd party tool.

If you mean 2010 solutions / custom code, then you will have to manually re-write to adhere to the new App model. Check out a similar answer:

[Moving SharePoint to the Cloud](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120017/moving-sharepoint-to-the-cloud/120023#120023)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online does not give the customer access to the Central Administration, and there are no Microsoft tools to help with migration from SharePoint Server 2010 to SharePoint Online.

So you have to be moved data manually or you may try third-party tools however this is unsupported by Microsoft.

[Office 365 Support Response.](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/45060.aspx)

Also have a look on this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/21c53734-ba8f-47f7-b160-5c1a6b3fb238/sharepoint-2010-to-office-365-migration?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious